# SQL - Querying top value for multiple columns

Tags: sql

```
Table1:
Name, Value A, Value B, Value C
```

I would like to find the largest Name by Value A, the largest Name by Value B and the largest Name by Value C. Does anyone have a quick way to do this? The table itself is rather large and I would really want to avoid running through it multiple times for each value.

Thank you!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Start by tagging your question properly.

Comment: Apologies and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an index on each of the columns `(a)`, `(b)`, and `(c)`, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.a = (select max(t2.a) from t t2) or
      t.b = (select max(t2.b) from t t2) or
      t.c = (select max(t2.c) from t t2) ;
```

The `where` clause should be able to make use of the indexes.  If not, you can split this into subqueries.  Something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.a = (select max(t2.a) from t t2) 
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.b = (select max(t2.b) from t t2) 
select t.*
from t
where t.c = (select max(t2.c) from t t2) ;
```

Comment: Thanks! However, given that the table that I'm selecting from is formed from a number of queries - this might lag it down quite abit. Is there an alternative way? Or would the only way to speed it up be to create temp table and reference that instead?

Comment: @TheodoreLee . . . You should ask another question.  That is entirely different from having a table.